# Passing get variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to pass get variable from my view to the controller and to the model also and load to my view again
without the use of form  like

```
$jcid=  $row['id']; // this id from other table which is parent.
$s = "SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE job_cat=$jcid";
$re = mysql_query($s);
$no = mysql_num_rows($re);
echo $no;
```

Thanks in advance

Amit

Comment: if you're asking about how to fetch the get variable, you may want to look at this. http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/139807/#689150

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: i have a category list of jobs whose jobs are added according to job category so i have made 2 tables namely job_cat and jobs in job_cat i have fetched all values from that tbl now i want the count of particular jobs for the particular category say itjobs(0) if no jobs in jobs tbl if their it should be updates to 1 or more as jobs are their for that job category . so i want to pass its pkey to the jobs tbl having foregin key how should i do it from codeigniter                      thanks for the patience for reading to my description

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using get param use like this

This can be your form url

`http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up`

`$this->uri->segment(3); // Will give you news`

Like wise in place of 3 replace with 4 will give you metro and so on. You can access this in controller.

Uri class in the codeigniter

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 0):

First use

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

And then

```
$data['$jcid'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
```